# xtrabackup restore a single database?

Tags: mysql, percona

Percona XtraBackup gets a lot of praise, from what I can see, but I find it incredibly frustrating. I'm using:

```
root@GR-00258:~# xtrabackup --version
xtrabackup version 2.4.9 based on MySQL server 5.7.13 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: a467167cdd4)
```

I can create backups of one or more single databases without problems, but there doesn't appear to be any way to restore them. The only way I have found is to restore them as a full backup into an empty `/var/lib/mysql`, which means mysql won't start up, of course. It seems like a remarkably poor tool for restore - what is the purpose of being able to make a backup of individual databases, if they cannot be restored?

Enough ranting - is there a way to get this to work, or am I just wasting my time? I know, I can use `mysqldump` into a csv file, but that is not an attractive option, when the databases are ~500GB - ~1TB.

Comment: [Per the Percona Docs](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/innobackupex/restoring_a_backup_ibk.html)  --  According to this, you may have to do some manual directory stripping and permission changes etc .. But seems pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percona XtraBackup allows you to make a physical backup of a MySQL datadir without blocking access for clients. It's significantly faster than `mysqldump` to make a backup.

Restoring is also very fast. All you have to do is copy the backup files to a new datadir (after doing the prepare step, which you could do at the time you create the backup).

When restoring a full backup, you can't do that when the destination MySQL Server is running. You must shut down `mysqld` then copy the files into place, make sure the files have the right ownership and permissions, then start `mysqld`.

It's not easy to import selected tables or schemas without overwriting. But it *is* possible:

You must use the `--export` option when you prepare the backup. Then you can import individual tablespaces to an existing MySQL datadir. But you must do this one tablespace at a time, unfortunately. There's no way to do it in one step for all tables in a schema. You should be able to write a script to do that.

See a complete example of importing tablespaces from a backup here: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/xtrabackup_bin/restoring_individual_tables.html

Comment: That seems to be for version 8.0 only - I can't seem to find the same documentation for earlier versions(?)

Comment: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/xtrabackup_bin/restoring_individual_tables.html

Comment: Literally just replace "/8.0/" in the URL with another version number.

Comment: I admit the XtraBackup documentation is badly organized.

Comment: Thanks for helping me - I've accepted your answer. I think it would be a really good idea if xtrabackup could simply restore individual databases - the very existence of the "--databases" option suggests that this functionality is supported.

Comment: Not if you actually read the documentation for that option and understand what it does! :-) It restricts the database(s) that are backed up. It does not change the way XtraBackup restores a backup. See also https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/innobackupex/partial_backups_innobackupex.html

Comment: What?! Read documentation? ;-)